# Can't put rows into array using sqlite3 on Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, sqlite

I have a code in Node.js that selects everything from a SQLite Database and print every row and it works, here's the code:

```
var sqlite3=require('sqlite3').verbose();

var db=new sqlite3.Database('./database.db',(err)=>{
    if(err){
        return console.error(err.message);
    }
    console.log('Connected...');
});

db.all('SELECT * FROM langs ORDER BY name',[],(err,rows)=>{
    if(err){
        return console.error(err.message);
    }
    rows.forEach((row)=>{
        console.log(row.name);
    });
});

db.close((err) => {
    if (err) {
        return console.error(err.message);
    }
    console.log('Database closed...');
});
```

It prints:

```
Connected...
C
Java
Database closed...
```

But when I try using this to get the rows into an array, it doesnt work:

```
var data=[];
db.all('SELECT * FROM langs ORDER BY name',[],(err,rows)=>{
    if(err){
        return console.error(err.message);
    }
    rows.forEach((row)=>{
        data.push(row);
    });
});

for(col in data){
    console.log(col.name);
}
```

It prints:

```
Connected...
Database closed...
```

**SOLUTION:** After modifying the code to work with `async/await` and updating Node to version 8.11.1, it works, code:

```
var data=[],records=[];

function getRecords(){
    return new Promise(resolve=>{
        db.all('SELECT * FROM langs ORDER BY name',[],(err,rows)=>{
            if(err){
                return console.error(err.message);
            }
            rows.forEach((row)=>{
                data.push(row);
            });

            resolve(data);
        });
    });
}

async function asyncCall(){
    records=await getRecords();

    records.forEach(e=>{
        console.log(e.name);
    });
}

asyncCall();
```

Comment: i may be missing something, but it looks like you don't have a `console.log` statement in your second implementation. did you want to print something specific? ... my mistake i see it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because `db.all` is `asynchronous`. Data array is not yet populated and you are trying to loop through it. Just move `for` loop inside and you're done.

Your final code should look like

```js
var data=[],
     records = [];
function getRecords(){
  return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
  db.all('SELECT * FROM langs ORDER BY name',[],(err,rows)=>{
    if(err){
        return console.error(err.message);
    }
    rows.forEach((row)=>{
        data.push(row);
    });
    
   resolve(data);
})
  
  })
}

(async function(){
  records = await getRecords();
})()
```

ps. It is not good idea to use `for(..in..)` you better use `forEach`

Comment: I need to pass that array through WebSocket, so I will need to put everything in there?

Comment: you can use `async/await` to get the data and use it where you want

Comment: well, I've updated as per to `async/await`. Now you can use records whenever you want

Comment: It gave me this error:

    (async function(){
       ^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token function
    at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:393:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:150:9)

Comment: there may be some syntax issue. try matching it with https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Comment: no, that didn't work, it says "function" is unexpected token