# Retrieve array of rows from SQLite database to NodeJS

Tags: node.js, sqlite

I have a SQLite database with a single table of several hundred thousand rows, each storing student data, a subject studied, and a grade that they received:

| StudentID | Subject | Grade |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Latin | A |
| 1 | Klingon | B |
| 2 | Latin | C |

I would like to retrieve a count of grades received (i.e., how many As, how many Bs). This will eventually go out into a React frontend and be formatted in a graph.

I have previously done this with Python but am learning NodeJS. When I run the below code I get an empty array returned. I suspect that my simplistic Python logic is being beaten by Node being asynchronous and therefore running through without waiting for the response to the query being returned. Is that likely or do I have an error in where/how I return the array? Is there best practice to achieve what I want here?

```
const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3');
const db = new sqlite3.Database('./my_db.db');

function countGrades() {
    rowData = [] // empty array to store data
    db.all("SELECT Grade, COUNT(StudentID) AS count FROM tbl_grades GROUP BY Grade", (error, rows) => {
        rows.forEach((row) => {
            console.log(row.count + " " + row.Grade); //this correctly outputs the data that I want
            rowData.push(row)
        })
    });
    return rowData
}

rowData = countGrades()
rowData.forEach((row) => {
    console.log(row)
})
```

Intended output is an array with a count of how many of each grade has been achieved:

```
[["A", 412,], ["B", 312], ["C", 564]... etc]
```

Comment: If `error` contains a value, you'll want to propagate that error to callers. I'm guessing error is populated and it's an issue with your path used to initialize `db`.

Comment: db.all is an asynchronous job, check this out
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50164935/cant-put-rows-into-array-using-sqlite3-on-node-js